# How can integer overflow protection be turned off?

Tags: integer, overflow, rust

My default Rust has integer overflow protect enabled, and will halt a program in execution on overflow. A large number of algorithms require overflow to function correctly (SHA1, SHA2, etc.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`Wrapping`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/num/struct.Wrapping.html) type, or use the [wrapping functions](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/?search=wrapping) directly. These disable the overflow checks. The `Wrapping` type allows you to use the normal operators as usual.

Also, when you compile your code in "release" mode (such as with `cargo build --release`), the overflow checks are omitted to improve performance. Do not rely on this though, use the above type or functions so that the code works even in debug builds.

Comment: For compatibility, observe that some of the wrapping functions aren’t stable until 1.2.0, but the Wrapping type is ready for use.

Answer (score 11):

[Francis Gagné's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31215217/155423) is absolutely the correct answer for your case, but there *is* a compiler option to disable overflow checks. I don't see any reason to use it, but it exists and might as well be known about:

```rust
#![allow(arithmetic_overflow)]

fn main() {
    dbg!(u8::MAX + u8::MAX);
}
```

#### Via Cargo

Set this in your [profile section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#overflow-checks):

```
[profile.dev]
overflow-checks = false
```

```
% cargo run -q
[src/main.rs:6] u8::MAX + u8::MAX = 254
```

#### Via `rustc`

Use the `-C overflow-checks` command line option:

```
% rustc overflow.rs -C overflow-checks=off

% ./overflow
[overflow.rs:6] u8::MAX + u8::MAX = 254
```

Comment: And it is even possible to use this flag with Cargo now: `cargo rustc -- -Z force-overflow-checks=no`, even on stable.

Comment: using `#![allow(arithmetic_overflow)]` did not prevent a panic from multiplication overflow when i used it. i ended up using `x.wrapping_mul(y)`.

Comment: Attribute in source code and compilation option(using cargo or rustc) are both needed to disable overflow protection.