# Is it expected that a too large bitshift is undefined behavior in Rust?

Tags: rust, undefined-behavior, bit-shift

When you run this code:

```
#![allow(exceeding_bitshifts)]

fn main() {
    const NUMBER: u64 = 0b_10101010;

    fn print_shift(i: u32) {
        println!("{:b}", NUMBER >> i);
    }

    print_shift(65);
    println!("{:b}", NUMBER >> 65);
}
```

You see that shifting the bits of a number with a value that exceed the bit length produces different behavior when doing at compile time or runtime.

Is it a normal behavior? Is it documented somewhere? This is not in the [list of documented undefined behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is **not** expected, but it is **not undefined behavior**. [This is "just" a bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/45239).

There *should* be no difference between how the constant is computed at compile time and how the value is computed at runtime. This is a hard problem in general as the machine performing the compilation and the machine running the code might have completely different architectures.

---

When talking about debug vs release builds, the behavior of "too large" bitshifts is expected, and is also **not undefined behavior**. The clue is in the error message:

> attempt to shift right with overflow

[Integer overflow is neither unsafe nor undefined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/behavior-not-considered-unsafe.html#integer-overflow):

> The Rust compiler does not consider the following behaviors unsafe,
>   though a programmer may (should) find them undesirable, unexpected, or
>   erroneous.
>
> - ...
> - Integer overflow

See also:

- [How can integer overflow protection be turned off?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31215139/155423)

Comment: The same function with same parameters (`x.shr(y)`) gives different answers in different calls. Is not this an UB?

Comment: @Boiethios I'm not sure that you are using the term *undefined behavior* correctly. `random()` (usually) returns different answers in different calls, but that doesn't mean that its behavior is undefined.

Comment: No, UB reffers specifically to cases where the specification doesn't define the behaviour, modern C/C++ compilers increasingly treat this as an optimisation opertunity leading to ever more confusing results when someone trips over one of the many cases of undefined behaviour in C/C++.

Comment: Rust on the other hand tries very hard to avoid undefined behaviour and where it can't be avoided (some pointer related operations are inherently unsafe) requires the programmer to explicitly aknowlege that with "unsafe" blocks.