# What are the exact semantics of Rust's shift operators?

Tags: rust, bit-shift

I tried to find exact information about how the `<<` and `>>` operators work on integers, but I couldn't find a clear answer ([the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Shr.html) is not that great in that regard).

There are two parts of the semantics that are not clear to me. First, what bits are "shifted in"?

- Zeroes are shifted in from one side (i.e. `0b1110_1010u8 << 4 == 0b1010_0000u8`), or
- the bits rotate (i.e. `0b1110_1010u8 << 4 == 0b1010_1110u8`), or
- it's unspecified (like overflowing behavior of integers is unspecified), or
- something else.

Additionally, how does shifts work with signed integers? Is the sign bit also involved in the shift or not? Or is this unspecified?

Comment: "Performs the `>>` operation." Well, that's not really detailed documentation indeed. I would suggest you open an issue to ask for more detailed documentation.

Comment: Note that the documentation of [`rotate_right`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.usize.html#method.rotate_right) specifies "Please note this isn't the same operation as `>>`!", so at least you can get from that that `>>` doesn't rotate bits.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> What are the exact semantics of Rust's shift operators?

There are none. The shift operators are a user-implementable trait and you can do basically anything you want in them. The documentation even shows an example of "[a]n implementation of `Shr` that spins a vector rightward by a given amount."

---

> how the `<<` and `>>` operators work on integers,

The reference has a section on [Arithmetic and Logical Binary Operators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#arithmetic-and-logical-binary-operators). Most usefully, it contains this footnote:

> Arithmetic right shift on signed integer types, logical right shift on unsigned integer types.

[Logical shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) and [arithmetic shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) are preexisting computer science terms with established definitions.

> Zeroes are shifted in

Yes.

> the bits rotate

No. There are separate methods for rotating [left](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.i32.html#method.rotate_left) and [right](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.i32.html#method.rotate_right).

Comment: It's also worth noting that merely shifting bits off the left edge of the number is not considered "overflow". Only shifting by an amount greater than or equal to the number of bits is considered overflow.

Answer (score 18):

The thin documentation on the traits `Shl` and `Shr` is intentional, so that they may adopt a behaviour that is most suitable for the type at hand (think newtypes!).

With that said, when it comes to the base integer types, the [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#arithmetic-and-logical-binary-operators) covers how they behave, with a bit of inference:

> - `<<`    | Left Shift        |   `std::ops::Shl`
> - `>>`    | Right Shift*      |   `std::ops::Shr`
>
> * Arithmetic right shift on signed integer types, logical right shift on unsigned integer types.

It also includes a few examples, which further clarifies that these are conventional logical/arithmetic shifts: zeros are inserted to the least significant bits on a left bit shift, and the most significant bit is extended for signed integers on a right bit shift. It is also [not a rotation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.rotate_left), as described in the methods `rotate_left` and `rotate_right`.

```
assert_eq!(13 << 3, 104);
assert_eq!(-10 >> 2, -3);
```

Moreover, shifting too many bits may be regarded as an arithmetic overflow, and is not undefined behaviour. See: [Is it expected that a too large bitshift is undefined behavior in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46714279/1233251)