# Why do we use mask for cutting bytes?

Tags: rust

So I guess this one is pretty stupid but I can't figure the answer by myself.

A few days ago I had to create a function that returns the strong byte of an unsigned integer. After a few researches on the web, I came up with this one:

```
fn strong_byte(num: u32) -> u8 {
  ((num >> 24) & 0xFF) as u8
}
```

But after searching again for a while I also found this one:

```
fn strong_byte(num: u32) -> u8 {
  (num << 24 >> 24) as u8
}
```

So I was wondering which form was the more performant? I tried to find benchmarks showing left shift vs bitmask performance, but didn't find anything...

I know the first syntax is by far the most used, but I can't understand why the second is not...

Comment: These don't do the same thing. The first returns the most significant byte of `num`. The second returns the least significant byte of `num`.

Comment: "So I was wondering which form was the more performant?" For such a common and trivial thing, if there was a significantly better way to do it, LLVM would optimize to that.

Comment: Also, in that first example, the mask is completely unnecessary, `(num >> 24) & 0xFF` == `num >> 24` for any 32 bits integer.

Comment: If the first example is amended to `num & 0xFF`, the question makes sense because they do the same thing. But "strong byte" is not a common term; I would say "least significant byte".

Comment: https://rust.godbolt.org/z/Hc_LgZ answers the question with regard to `num & 0xFF` vs `num << 24 >> 24`: at `-C opt-level=0` `lsb_shift` is much slower. At `-C opt-level=1` they are the same, and at higher optimization levels they're merged into a single function.

Comment: @trentcl Interesting with no optimizations. I wonder why the compiler feels the need to write each intermediate result to the stack and read it back immediately for the shift version, but it doesn't deem this necessary for the bitwise and.

Comment: @Justin because there are no intermediate results for the bitwise and, it is a single operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Credits goes to others as well, see comments below the question.

## Terminology

What is a *strong byte*? You should use [Least significant byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Least_significant_byte) (LSB) or [Most significant byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Most_significant_byte) (MSB).

## Your functions

I added `_1` and `_2` suffixes to the names, just to distinguish between them.

```rust
fn strong_byte_1(num: u32) -> u8 {
  ((num >> 24) & 0xFF) as u8
}
```

```rust
fn strong_byte_2(num: u32) -> u8 {
  (num << 24 >> 24) as u8
}
```

These two functions do different things. Guess what the output of ...

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{}", strong_byte_1(255));
    println!("{}", strong_byte_2(255));
}
```

... is. `_1` returns `0` and `_2` returns `255`. The `_1` returns MSB and the `_2` returns LSB. You have to fix them if you'd like to compare them.

Also `strong_byte_1` implementation contains unnecessary bit mask. `((num >> 24) & 0xFF) as u8` equals to `(num >> 24) as u8`. Check the Shepmaster's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51571371/581190) here. The `>>` operation contains footnote:

> Arithmetic right shift on signed integer types, logical right shift on unsigned integer types.

`u32` is unsigned -> logical right shift (see [Logical shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift)), which means:

```
0b11111111000000000000000000000000 >> 1 == 0b01111111100000000000000000000000
0b01111111100000000000000000000000 >> 1 == 0b00111111110000000000000000000000
0b00111111110000000000000000000000 >> 1 == 0b00011111111000000000000000000000
...
0b00000000000000000000000111111110 >> 1 == 0b00000000000000000000000011111111
```

## LSB

Let's rewrite them, so both do return LSB.

```rust
fn lsb_1(num: u32) -> u8 {
  (num & 0xFF) as u8
}
```

```rust
fn lsb_2(num: u32) -> u8 {
  (num << 24 >> 24) as u8
}
```

What's more performant?

### rust 1.36 & opt-level=0

```
example::lsb_1:
        and     edi, 255
        mov     al, dil
        ret

example::lsb_2:
        push    rax
        shl     edi, 24
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], edi
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 4]
        shr     eax, 24
        mov     dword ptr [rsp], eax
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp]
        mov     cl, al
        mov     al, cl
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

### rust 1.36.0 & opt-level=1

```
example::lsb_1:
        mov     eax, edi
        ret

example::lsb_2:
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
```

## MSB

```rust
fn msb(num: u32) -> u8 {
  (num >> 24) as u8
}
```

### rust 1.36.0 & opt-level=0

```
example::msb:
        sub     rsp, 4
        shr     edi, 24
        mov     dword ptr [rsp], edi
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp]
        mov     cl, al
        mov     al, cl
        add     rsp, 4
        ret
```

### rust 1.36.0 & opt-level=1

```
example::msb:
        mov     eax, edi
        shr     eax, 24
        ret
```

## Conclusion

What's more performant? Look at the compiler output (assembly), consult target architecture documentation, etc. What compiler are you using? Which version? What is your target architecture? In other words - your question is too broad.

The mentioned [Compiler Explorer](https://rust.godbolt.org) is a nice tool for checking what the compiler output is.

Generally speaking, you should finish your program, make it working and then optimise. Your program will be doing lot of other things and it will contain way more bottlenecks. Measure, optimise, rollback, optimise, measure, commit, ... But do it with the final product, no just simple routines. You can spend non trivial amount of time on premature (thus useless) optimisations. And then you can find that you optimised one routine, but your program is waiting for something else (network, ...), has issues elsewhere, ...