# Cargo build --release option ignored when testing overflow

Tags: rust, build, release, rust-cargo, mode

I've been stepping through the Programming Rust book and wanted to observe the two's complement wrapping, so simple code of:

```
fn main() {

    let mut x: u8 = 255;
    println!("the value of x is {}", x) ;
    x = 255 + 1 ;
    println!("The value of x now is {}",x) ;
}
```

when I try and compile this with Cargo as per the guide, I run
cargo build --release
which in the book says will let it compile without overflow protection, but it won't compile. I get the protection error

|
6 |     x = 255 + 1 ;

|     ^^^^^^^^^^^ attempt to compute `u8::MAX + 1_u8`, which would overflow

Can you explain what I'm doing wrong please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can integer overflow protection be turned off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31215139/how-can-integer-overflow-protection-be-turned-off)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the value is not checked dynamically during run-time (it wont `panic` and would overflow) but still statically checked for (if possible) during compile time.

In this case the compiler is able to determine at compile time what you're trying to do and prevents you from doing it.

That being said if you look at the compiler output you can see the following message:

> note: `#[deny(arithmetic_overflow)]` on by default

You'll see this message regardless of the optimization level.

If you'd like to observe the overflow put the following `inner attribute` at the top of your source file.

```
#![allow(arithmetic_overflow)]
```

Or, if you're compiling with `rustc` directly you can pass the following flags:

```
-O -A arithmetic_overflow
```

The `rustc` docs show that the following lints are on by default (regardless of optimization level)

- ambiguous_associated_items
- arithmetic_overflow
- conflicting_repr_hints
- const_err
- ill_formed_attribute_input
- incomplete_include
- invalid_type_param_default
- macro_expanded_macro_exports_accessed_by_absolute_paths
- missing_fragment_specifier
- mutable_transmutes
- no_mangle_const_items
- order_dependent_trait_objects
- overflowing_literals
- patterns_in_fns_without_body
- pub_use_of_private_extern_crate
- soft_unstable
- unconditional_panic
- unknown_crate_types
- useless_deprecated

Comment: Another excellent explanation thanks WBuck.

Answer (score 2):

When you write a *literal* `255+1` in your code, the compiler evaluates the expression at compile-time and sees the overflow immediately, whether in debug or release mode. When the book says that `--release` disables overflow protection, it's talking about *runtime* checks. You can see the difference with this code:

```
fn increment (x: u8) -> u8 { x + 1 }

fn main() {
    let x = 255;
    println!("x: {}, x+1: {}", x, increment (x));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=b92b7f3f89d48553601670b24a809323)

If you run this code in debug mode, you get:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to add with overflow', src/main.rs:1:30
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

But if you run it in release mode, you get:

```
x: 255, x+1: 0
```